# How to show post from category select

Tags: theme-development, categories

This code is in my `functions.php`:

```
array( "name" => "Headline",
"type" => "section"),
array( "type" => "open"),

array( "name" => "Headline  Categories",
"desc" => "Choose a category from which featured posts are drawn",
"id" => $shortname."_headline",
"type" => "select",
"options" => $wp_getcat,
"std" => "Select a category"),

array( "type" => "close"),
```

Now, how to show posts from category select on `page.php` or page template?

Comment: This code is incomplete. What you have posted doesn't actually _do_ anything.

Comment: i read on this www.colorlabsproject.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-wordpress-admin-panel-part-ii/
but i don't know how to emplementation on frontend,
can you help me?

Comment: what i mean before is, how to show all post in select category by panel themes, and now its work.thanks

Comment: But ___what is your solution___? So that other people can benefit?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to model this on theme options code. You can't do that. That is backend code. As written, this question is very broad-- I am tempted to vote to close as "too broad"-- but I will offer bare bones code to get you started:

```
echo '<form method="post">';
  wp_dropdown_categories();
  echo '<input type="submit" name="catsearch" value="Submit" />';
echo '</form>';
if (isset($_GET['cat']) && ctype_digit($_GET['cat'])) {
  $qry = new WP_Query( 
    array(
      'cat' => (int)$_GET['cat'] 
    )
  );
  var_dump($qry);
}
```

You will need to consult the documentation for [`wp_dropdown_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) and [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), and will probably need to do a bit a research on HTML forms and basic PHP.